# Is possible retrieve multiples actorRef from ActorSelection?

Tags: java, akka, actor

I have try get multiples ActorRef from ActorSelection. Someone know if is possible ?

My code

```java
ActorRef actorRef = Await.result(getContext().actorSelection("/user/regions/*").resolveOne(timeout), timeout.duration());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible using `resolveOne`, as the name suggests it returns a single reference. You could send a message to the `ActorSelection` which would send the message to every Actor matching the selection, and have those actors reply. If you use the built-in `Identify` message, then you wouldn't need to alter the receiving actors at all. From the docs at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Identifying_Actors_via_Actor_Selection:

> Messages can be sent via the ActorSelection and the path of the
>   ActorSelection is looked up when delivering each message. If the
>   selection does not match any actors the message will be dropped.
>
> To acquire an ActorRef for an ActorSelection you need to send a
>   message to the selection and use the sender() reference of the reply
>   from the actor. There is a built-in Identify message that all Actors
>   will understand and automatically reply to with a ActorIdentity
>   message containing the ActorRef. This message is handled specially by
>   the actors which are traversed in the sense that if a concrete name
>   lookup fails (i.e. a non-wildcard path element does not correspond to
>   a live actor) then a negative result is generated. Please note that
>   this does not mean that delivery of that reply is guaranteed, it still
>   is a normal message.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks!